# How to pass a third value in a cell to another table view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a `UITableViewController` with a `textLabel` and a `detailTextLabel`, the thing is that I want to pass a let's say "hidden" third value which has an `URL`, so when I touch the row to the next `UITableViewController` I could use the delegate `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`  to get the URL but how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a dictionary to the next TableView. Import the SecondTableView controller .h file into your FirstTableView controller and then reference the target dictionary. You will also need to implement prepareForSegue and call it in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Something like this:

In didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (make sure to set the segue identifier in Storyboard if you are using it).

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toSecondTableViewController" sender:nil];
```

In SecondTableViewController.h create your dictionary

```
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSMutableDictionary *selectedDictionary;
```

Make sure to synthesize this in the SecondTableViewController.m file.

and then in your FirstTableViewController

```
#import SecondTableViewController.h 
//prepareForSegue
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toSecondTableViewController"])
    {
        //create the dictionary to store the information from the array
        NSDictionary *dictionaryToPass;
//MainTable is your TableView in your TableViewController
        NSIndexPath *indexpath = [self.MainTable indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSLog(@"IndexPath is: %@",indexpath);
        //load correct information based on indexpath selected

            dictionaryToPass = [array objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];

        //create the view for the segue
        SecondTableViewController *secondTable = segue.destinationViewController;

//pass the dictionary
        seriesTable.selectedDictionary = dictionaryToPass;
    }
}
```

You can then reference keys in the selectedDictionary in your SecondTableViewController and get that URL.

Comment: Or maybe with NSUserDefaults? Just get the value from the NSDictionary  and when preparingForSegue then send the value to NSUserDefaults, then in the next tableview when viewWillAppear recover the URL with NSUserDefaults and ready to go... What do you think?

Comment: That would also work I suppose. If it is being populated from an array, a dictionary is easy and you can just select which position in the array to populate the dictionary with based on which cell they selected.

Comment: I've just tried the way you mentioned, and I'm getting a null value, and then going back to the last controller and going forward I'm getting the expected last value, any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: I just updates my code. Make sure you are not off by one on your index path, and that your second dictionary is synthesized. THis is assuming storyboard, but it still should be the same code with a slight change to the segue if you are not using it. It does not matter really if you create the dictionary inside prepareForSegue, or outside, just make sure to set dictionaryToPass = nil if you set it outside prepareForSegue so it is empty for other selections.